# Convert unicode to a readable string

Tags: r, twitter, unicode, utf-8

My object in **R** contains the following unicode which are extracted from twitter.

> \xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xb0\xe0\xaf\x8d
>   \xe0\xae\x9a\xe0\xaf\x82\xe0\xae\xb0\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xaf\xe0\xae\xbe
>   \xe0\xae\x9a\xe0\xaf\x86\xe0\xae\xaf\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xa4
>   \xe0\xae\x89\xe0\xae\xa4\xe0\xae\xb5\xe0\xae\xbf
>   \xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\x95
>   \xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xaf\x81\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xaf\xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xae\xbe\xe0\xae\xa9\xe0\xae\xa4\xe0\xaf\x81!'
>   - \xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xaf\x86\xe0\xae\xb2\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xae\xbe\xe0\xae\xb5\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xb2\xe0\xaf\x8d
>   \xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xaf\x86\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xb4\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xa4
>   \xe0\xae\x9a\xe0\xaf\x80\xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xae\xbe\xe0\xae\xa9\xe0\xaf\x8d

I need to convert them to human readable strings.  If I just put this in a string, e.g.

```
x <- "\xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xb0\xe0\xaf\x8d \xe0\xae\x9a\xe0\xaf\x82\xe0\xae\xb0\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xaf\xe0\xae\xbe \xe0\xae\x9a\xe0\xaf\x86\xe0\xae\xaf\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xa4 \xe0\xae\x89\xe0\xae\xa4\xe0\xae\xb5\xe0\xae\xbf \xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\x95 \xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xaf\x81\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xaf\xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xae\xbe\xe0\xae\xa9\xe0\xae\xa4\xe0\xaf\x81!' - \xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xaf\x86\xe0\xae\xb2\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xae\xbe\xe0\xae\xb5\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xb2\xe0\xaf\x8d \xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xaf\x86\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xb4\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\xa4 \xe0\xae\x9a\xe0\xaf\x80\xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xae\xbe\xe0\xae\xa9\xe0\xaf\x8d"
```

it displays as an unreadable mess.  How can I get it to display using the actual characters?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it's a good question.  The string really is UTF-8 encoded, and will display as garbage on Windows unless you declare it that way, using something like `Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"`.  If you do that you'll see the text (in Tamil, according to Google Translate).

Comment: @user2554330 it's reopened if you'd like to post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the hex codes like `\xe0\xae\xa8\xe0...` to a string, R doesn't know how they are intended to be interpreted, so it assumes the encoding for the current locale on your computer.  On most modern Unix-based systems these days, that would be UTF-8, so for example on a Mac your string displays as

```
> x
[1] "நடிகர் சூர்யா செய்த உதவி மிக முக்கியமானது!' - டெல்டாவில் நெகிழ்ந்த சீமான்"
```

which I assume is the correct display.  Google Translate recognizes it as being written in Tamil.

However, on Windows it displays unreadably.  On my Windows 10 system, I see

```
> x
[1] "à®¨à®Ÿà®¿à®•à®°à¯ à®šà¯‚à®°à¯à®¯à®¾ à®šà¯†à®¯à¯à®¤ à®‰à®¤à®µà®¿ à®®à®¿à®• à®®à¯à®•à¯à®•à®¿à®¯à®®à®¾à®©à®¤à¯!' - à®Ÿà¯†à®²à¯à®Ÿ
```

because it uses the code page corresponding to the Latin1 encoding, which is wrong for that string.  To get it to display properly on Windows, you need to tell R that it is encoded in UTF-8 by declaring its encoding:

```
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
```

Then it will display properly in Windows as well, which solves your problem.

For others trying to do this, it's important to know that there are only a few values that work this way.  You can declare the encoding to be `"UTF-8"`, `"latin1"`, `"bytes"` or `"unknown"`.  "unknown" means the local encoding on the machine, "bytes" means it shouldn't be interpreted as characters at all.  If your string has a different encoding, you need to use a different approach: convert to one of the encodings that R knows about.

For example, the string

```
x <- "\xb4\xde\xd1\xe0\xde\xd5 \xe3\xe2\xe0\xde"
```

is Russian encoded in ISO 8859-5.  On a system where that was the local encoding it would display properly, but on mine it displays using the hex codes.  To get it to display properly I need to convert it to UTF-8 using

```
y <- iconv(x, from="ISO8859-5", to="UTF-8")
```

Then it will display properly as `[1] "Доброе утро"`.  You can see the full list of encodings that `iconv()` knows about using `iconvlist()`.